# "Failed to create sample data" while running configuration wizard

Tags: configuration, error, installation

Fresh install of SharePoint 2010 Enterprise on a fresh Server 2008 R2 VM - default single-server isntallation. Installation succeeded so I ran the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard. I had to run it a couple times to eventually get to step 8 where it is creating the sample data. This is where it failed and it continues to do so. Here is the error from the log, I'm not sure what to check/do in order to fix this.

```
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  ERR                  The ServerBindings or SecureBindings property was not found for IIS schema IIsWebServer
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                    Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                      Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                        Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                        Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                      Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                    Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  INF                  Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  ERR                  An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WebSiteCollection.GetServerBindings(PropertyCollection properties, Boolean& secure, String& ip, Int32& port, String& host)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WebSiteCollection.TryGetIisMetaData(DirectoryEntry entry)
05/10/2011 13:31:42  1  ERR                  Failed to retrieve the server bindings with an internal InvalidOperationException
```

That occurs a few times - sounds like it's complaining about a missing HTTPS binding - and then farther down...

```
05/10/2011 13:52:32  17  ERR              Task evalprovision has failed with an unknown exception 
05/10/2011 13:52:32  17  ERR              Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The URL '_catalogs/wp/owatasks.dwp' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8107058A): <nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>The URL '_catalogs/wp/owatasks.dwp' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPContentDatabase database, SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, String quotaTemplate, String sscRootWebUrl, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.InstallMySiteHost(Guid partitionID)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.Install()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.ProvisionServiceApplicationsAndProxies()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

[View the full log file here.](http://cid-4817eaf499afe674.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/StackExchange/PSCDiagnostics%5E_5%5E_10%5E_2011%5E_13%5E_29%5E_49%5E_590%5E_1561676423.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put in the hotfix for R2?  I've done this before with success.

Jie Li mentions the hotfix and steps on his blog - [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/opal/installation-notice-for-sharepoint-2010-public-beta)

athough it mentions Beta I believe this is still needed for R2

Comment: Thanks. That actually didn't work because it's not a valid hotfix for my system. But I did install some pending Windows Updates and ran it again. This time I am getting SQL timeouts so that's...better?

Comment: Better but I don't recall much about that except making sure that your SQL account has the right permissions.

Comment: I accepted your answer because 1) it was the only answer and 2) it reminded me to install pending updates which ended up getting me passed the error. Thanks.